# Geocoder doesn't get lat lon on model

Tags: ruby, geocoding, rails-geocoder, sinatra-activerecord

I am using the Sinatra ruby framework.I have a delivery model(see below). I am using the geocoder gem with ActiveRecord.

I have the fields **latitude** and **longitude** in my schema.

When I use the console to get the Geocode:

```
Geocoder.search delivery.address
```

I get the response from the google API.

But it doesn't populate the lat\lon fields. I can't imagine why.

I am using an API key in app.rb like so:

```
  Geocoder.configure(
    api_key: ENV['GEOCODER_API_KEY']
  )
```

And I know the key works since I am getting responses for relatively high number of API calls per second.(Without the api key it's a call every 10 sec or so, or it returns an quota error)

This seems like a simple issue, but I can't figure it out. Would appreciate the help.

**Delivery.rb**

```
require 'sinatra/shopify-sinatra-app'
require 'geocoder'
# This is the delivery model. It holds all of the data
# associated with the delivery such as the orrder and  shop it belongs to .

class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord
  has_many :delivery_states, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :fulfillment_service
  validates :order_id, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  has_one :courier, through: :fulfillment_service
  #after_create :add_delivery_state
  attr_accessor :latitude, :longitude
  #geocoder setup
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode#, :if => lambda{ |obj| obj.address1_changed? || obj.city_changed? || obj.province_changed? || obj.country_changed? }

  def address
    #check address1 is not a variation of POB
    addr = address1 unless address1.match(/(?:P(?:ost(?:al)?)?[\.\-\s]*(?:(?:O(?:ffice)?[\.\-\s]*)?B(?:ox|in|\b|\d)|o(?:ffice|\b)(?:[-\s]*\d)|code)|box[-\s\b]*\d)/i)
    [addr, city, province, country].join(',')
  end

  def add_delivery_state(status=0,ref_number=nil)
    if self.delivery_states.count>0
      ref_number = self.delivery_states.last.courier_reference unless ref_number
    else
      ref_number = 0 unless ref_number
    end
    self.delivery_states<<DeliveryState.new(delivery_status:status,courier_reference:ref_number)
  end
  def delivery_state
    self.delivery_states.last.delivery_status
  end
  def courier_reference
  self.delivery_states.count>0 ? self.delivery_states.last.courier_reference : "0"
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm confused what's not working here.  Are you saying some instances of `Delivery` have nil in the database?  Do you have an example address that produced this?

Comment: @Anthony, the thing that is not working is the geocode. i.e. an instance of Delivery has an #address that returns a value which works when using Geocoder.search delivery.address. However, attributes :latitude and :longitude are both nil.

Comment: As for an example, none of the addresses I tried populated lat\lon fields.

Comment: Can you show us in a console -> `d = Delivery.find(some_id)`; `d.address`, `d.update(updated_at: Time.now)` and show us the logs and result of `d`?

Comment: d = Delivery.find(42) =>  #<Delivery id: 42, fulfillment_service_id: "8", shop_id: "9", order_id: "461102186599", created_at: "2018-04-02 13:02:35", updated_at: "2018-04-02 13:02:58", request_params: "{\"id\":426686742631,\"order_id\":461102186599,\"status...", latitude: nil, longitude: nil, address1: "23 haneviem st", province: nil, country: "Israel", city: "Jerusalem">

Comment: d.address
 => "23 haneviem st,Jerusalem,,Israel"

Comment: after update =>  d
 => #<Delivery id: 42, fulfillment_service_id: "8", shop_id: "9", order_id: "461102186599", created_at: "2018-04-02 13:02:35", updated_at: "2018-04-02 16:30:37", request_params: "{\"id\":426686742631,\"order_id\":461102186599,\"status...", latitude: nil, longitude: nil, address1: "23 haneviem st", province: nil, country: "Israel", city: "Jerusalem">

Comment: From what I see, the geocode will execute after validation. In the previous comment, after loading the `Delivery` can you please execute `d.valid?` and then inspect the object to see if the fields are populated? Is there any case that you have saved the `Delivery` objects before adding the `geocode` functionality?

Comment: @LazarusLazaridis d.valid? => true.  And inspecting d. still has lat\lon nil. While having Delivery objects saved before adding geocoder, I tried  12 different addresses after. The example above is one of the 12.

Comment: Something else is going on with your code - I'm able to get it to work with what you provided: `#<Delivery:0x0000000349f8d8 latitude: 31.7839134, longitude: 35.2235753, address1: "23 haneviem st", province: nil, country: "Israel", city: "Jerusalem">`

Comment: Here's the code: https://gist.github.com/allcentury/2b557701a2b3625534a9e44118e90f9b

Comment: @Anthony thanks. I will look into it tomorrow. Could it be an issue with using first_or_create! to create an instance? Or not passing any value to lat\lon fields on creation( I saw you were passing nil explicitly when initializing a Delivery instance).